# In Grub Rescue, boot folder is missing

Tags: boot, grubrescue

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on a virtual machine. I am getting following error whenever I power on VMware instance where Ubuntu is installed.

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
Entering rescue mode
grub rescue>
```

I did go through a lot of posts regarding this issue and watched several videos on YouTube but could not find any post/video that addresses the issue I am facing. I entered following commands in grub rescue.

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) (fd0)
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos5)
(hd0,msdos5): Filesystem is unknown.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)
(hd0,msdos1): Filesystem is ext2.
```

After doing ls on (hd0,msdos1) partition, I get following subfolders. It can be seen that boot folder (where i386-pc file is present) is completely missing.

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)/
./ ../ VMware-uid-0/ dev/ proc/ run/ sys/ usr
```

Therefore, I am not sure how to resolve this error as boot folder itself is missing.

Any help on this issue will be deeply appreciated!!

Comment: Furthermore, booting into the Live CD, you will find that `/i386-pc` is missing from `/boot/grub`.  Using EXT2 /boot partition at 128 mb.  PC does not use EFI/UEFI.  Was installing via 16.04.3 Ubuntu MATE desktop.

Comment: Also trying to use this as the primary OS for this computer.  hmm

Answer (score 0):

Re-install.  Select "do something else".  Set your partitions as you desire.  Do not create a /boot partition since it won't be used.  Use the drop-down (ubuntu 16.04.3) to select your windows device as the location for the boot installation.  If you have an existing Windows installation, this problem will always occur.  You must put the boot on the partition of the Windows installation.  It's the only solution that works every time.

This is relevant for 14, 15, 16, 17 (all versions) and probably earlier releases.